# Hamiltonian: Commutator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a Hamiltonian:
$$H:\mathcal{D}(H)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad H=H^*$$

and an operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad A=A^*$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\mathcal{D}_0\subseteq\mathcal{D}:=\mathcal{D}(H)\cap\mathcal{D}(A)$$

with invariant core:
$$e^{i\alpha A}\mathcal{D}_0\subseteq\mathcal{D}_0:\quad\overline{H_0}=H$$

Introduce the form:
$$s(\varphi,\psi):=i\langle A\varphi,H\psi\rangle-i\langle H\varphi,A\psi\rangle\quad(\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal{D})$$

bounded-below on:
$$s_0(\varphi,\varphi)\geq\sigma\|\varphi\|^2\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{D}_0)$$

Regard its operator:
$$\hat{s_0}(\varphi,\psi)=\langle i[H,A]_0\varphi,\psi\rangle$$

Then it extends:
$$\mathcal{D}(i[H,A]_0)\supseteq\mathcal{D}(H)\implies s(\varphi,\psi)=\langle i[H,A]_0\varphi,\psi\rangle$$

Giving rise to:
$$\hat{s}(\varphi,\psi)=\langle i[H,A]\varphi,\psi\rangle$$

How can I prove this from scratch?